# Prevent dates from being converting when localizing in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I am localizing an app. The app makes calls to an API that I do not have control over. When posting a request to the API, one of the expected values is a date string in the following format:

```
"Fri, 15 Mar 2019 15:53:14"
```

When switching application language to Spanish the date is applied to the date parameter as:

```
"vie, 15 mar 2019 15:48:42"
```

which makes sense. However, it causes the API to fail. If I had control over it, I would be passing the date in seconds, rather than a string, but unfortunately I do not own the API.

Does anyone know how to prevent dates from being converted when localizing?

Thanks!

Comment: How is that string created? Are you using a DateFormatter? If yes: did you try to set the formatter's locale explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most the formatters, there is [locale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1411973-locale) property which is the `locale` of the device by default. You can modify it :

`dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")`

Thanks to rmaddy

Prefer  "en_US_POSIX" which is invariant in time.

> if the US, at some point in the future, changes the way it formats
>   dates, "en_US" will change to reflect the new behaviour, but
>   "en_US_POSIX" will not)

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: You should probably use `en_US_POSIX` to avoid possible issues with the time format.